# Why is this If statement not executing the code?

Tags: c, if-statement, response, generator

I've checked all syntax.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char * response;
  int anger = 0;
  int correct = 0;
  printf("type Dice");
  scanf("%s", response);
  if (response == "Dice"){
    printf("Good Job!");
    correct = 1;
  }
}
```

I an trying to make a response generator and the is statement isn't working. I tried setting the variable response to the correct answer and the if statement worked so I was thinking that maybe something was wrong with my scanf. I'm a beginner in C.

Comment: `response` is uninitialized.

Comment: Something is wrong with `scanf` but not limited to...Unallocated `response`. Comparison with string literal.

Comment: you cannot use `==` to compare strings in c, actually you don't have string, you have uninitialized pointer to char

Comment: i added scanf("%s", &response); to my code and i got the sam e response

Comment: that's not the only issue. You *cannot* compare strings using `==` operator.

Comment: This is how buffer-overrun vulnerabilities happen

Comment: What did you do exactly when you "checked all syntax" ?

Comment: Do you see any compiler warnings? You should to.

Comment: #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main(){
      char * response;
      int anger = 0;
      int correct = 0;
      printf("type Dice");
      scanf("%s", &response);
      int compare = strncmp(response, "Dice", 20);
      if (compare == 0)
        printf("Good Job!");
      return 0;
    }

Comment: I did not see any compiler warnings i just didn't work and by check all syaax  meant I checked to see is I had the if statement's structure correct and well as the scans

Comment: @ConnorKC Make sure you use `-Wall` when you compile, to get all warnings.

Comment: There are two main problems — not making `response` point to anything useful, and then not comparing the strings properly.  I duplicated this to the 'compare strings' problem, but there's likely also a plausible duplicate for 'make sure your pointers point somewhere valid'.

Comment: how do I use -Wall?

Comment: Don't vandalise your questions or edit them leaving answers without context!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did `char * response`. This makes a pointer variable to a character. Right now it is not pointing to any memory(it is some garbage value). `scanf` stores user input in consecutive memory addresses starting from the one pointed by `response`. as `response` is uninitialised, the input may not necessarily be stored on the stack(Don't want that).

Now when you do`response=="Dice"` it doesn't mean anything at all.

---

Some pretty basic stuff on arrays and pointers and their comparison.

```
int arr[10];
```

now `arr` points to the first member of the array, `arr+1` points to second, `arr+2` to third and so on. `arr[i]` is a shorthand way of saying `*(arr+i)`.

---

String is also an array of characters.

```
char *str1="Hello";
char *str2="Hello";
if(str1==str2){...}
```

What the if statement in line three here does is, it compares to pointers, ie it checks whether they both point to the same location. Since this is not true, execution won't go into the if block. What you want to do is compare the strings character by character. There is an inbuilt function in `string.h` called `strcmp()` which does that.

Comment: The funny thing that the last example can actually evaluate to `true`, since `str1` and `str2` are pointing to equal string literals and the compiler might very well to decide not to duplicate them and have only one `"Hello"` allocated.

Comment: You must have got a string literal comparison warning. DO NOT IGNORE THE COMPILER WARNINGS. They are there for a reason

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Not sure the compiler would do that since compiler would want to leave scope for change later on in the code

Comment: Yes it will: https://ideone.com/EbivBo .BTW, these should be pointers (fixed it for you..). Compiler doesn't care about future changes. It is optimizing here and now.

Comment: Well in the program down the flow we are attempting to change any of the two strings. The compiler can possibly make `str1` and `str2` point to same location as otherwise change in one string will change the other

Comment: No! String literals are read only. Attempting to change them is undefined behavior

Comment: "now arr points to the first member of the array" - Definitively **not**. `arr` is an array, not a pointer! You might want to find out why `arr + 0` actually **does**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use == to compare strings. Use strcmp() instead.  If it returns 0, they're identical.

```
if (strcmp(response,"Dice")==0){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Have you even read the comments?

Comment: Not endorsing the rest of the code, but this was the problem that was preventing it from compiling.

Comment: I don't think it was preventing the compiling. It should have given a bunch of warnings, yes.

Comment: weird thing is it didn't give me any warnings?

Comment: Also I put in the strain cap and I gave me non zero status here is my code#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
  char * response;
  int anger = 0;
  int correct = 0;
  printf("type Dice");
  scanf("%s", &response);
  int compare = strncmp(response, "Dice", 20);
  if (compare == 0)
    printf("Good Job!");
  return 0;
}